# How to pass sendgrid email template ID to mail send function?

Tags: laravel-5, sendgrid, email-templates

I saw lot of thread is there to explain send email with template using sendgrid.
But I have email template in third party sendgrid server not in my project folder.
Only template ID is with me.
I am using [this](https://packagist.org/packages/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver) package and my email send function is like that as explain in the readme.

```
\Mail::send('view', $data, function (Message $message) {
$message
    ->to('foo@example.com', 'foo_name')
    ->from('bar@example.com', 'bar_name')
    ->embedData([
        'category' => 'user_group1',
        'unique_args' => [
            'user_id' => 123
        ]
    ], 'sendgrid/x-smtpapi');
});
```

when I pass a view in my views folder variable 'view' it works well.
But my question is how to pass template ID in the sendgrid and use that template from my code ?

Or any other way to work with sendgrid template with Laravel ?
Please suggest if there is any other library better than this.

Please help.

Comment: I added the line `$message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', json_encode($js));`  it works. but nothing change in the email.

Comment: did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 4):

After a very big research on how to do this, I created my own class (including a notification) for laravel 5.3.

Here is the class

```
<?php
    namespace App\Notifications;
    use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
    //This example use the official's sendgrid php helper (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php)
    //You should install it before with composer require "sendgrid/sendgrid"
    class ExampleNotification extends Notification
    {
        use Queueable;
        public $api_key;
        public $sg;
        public $subs;
        public $template_id;
        public $to;
        public $from;
        public $subject;
        /**
         * Create a new notification instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct( $data, $message )
        {
            $this->api_key = "Your Sendgrid Api Key";
            $this->sg = new \SendGrid($this->api_key);
            $this->data = $data;
            $this->message = $message;
            $this->from = "example@gmail.com";
            //select message configuration method based on the message name
            $this->selectMessage();
        }
        /**
         * Get the notification's delivery channels.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $notifiable
         * @return array
         */
        public function via($notifiable)
        {
            //We should disable the automatic email provider from laravel
            // return ['mail'];
        }
        /**
         * Get the mail representation of the notification.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $notifiable
         * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
         */
        public function toMail($notifiable)
        {
            return (new MailMessage)
                        ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                        ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com')
                        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');

        }
        /**
         * Get the array representation of the notification.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $notifiable
         * @return array
         */
        public function toArray($notifiable)
        {
            return [
                //
            ];
        }

        /**
         * Handler for different messages or templates that you use in sendgrid
         *
         * @return void
         */
        private function selectMessage(){
            if( $this->message == "test_message")
                $this->testMessage();
        }
        /**
         * Test message's configuration
         *
         * @return void
         */
        private function testMessage(){
            $this->template_id = "your sendgrid template id";
            $this->to = $this->data->email;

            $this->subs = [
                "-yoursubcode-" => "Hello"
            ];
            $this->subject = "Your Subject";
            $this->sendTransactionEmail();
        }
        /**
         * Setup personalizations for sendgrind v3 mail
         *
         * @param \Sendgrid\Email Configured Email variable with the destination email
         *
         * @return \Sendgrid\Personalization Configured Personalizations for the mail 
         */
        private function personalizeEmail( $to ){
            $personalization = new \Sendgrid\Personalization();
            $personalization->addTo($to);
            foreach ($this->subs as $key => $value) {
                $personalization->addSubstitution($key,$value);    
            }

            return $personalization;
        }
        /**
         * Send the email via sendgrid 
         *
         * @return Object Http response from sendgrid
         */
        public function sendTransactionEmail(){

            $from = new \SendGrid\Email(null, $this->from);
            $to = new \SendGrid\Email(null, $this->to);

            //This should be at least 1 character even if it is empty
            $content = new \SendGrid\Content("text/html", " ");
            $mail = new \SendGrid\Mail($from, $this->subject, $to, $content);
            $mail->setTemplateId($this->template_id);

            $personalization = $this->personalizeEmail($to);
            $mail->addPersonalization($personalization);

            //Sending the email via sengrid api v3
            $response = $this->sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
        }
    }
    //Example usage of a notifiable model class
    //Remember to use use App\Notifications\ExampleNotification 
    //in your controller or the class that you want to apply it
    $user->notify(new ExampleNotification( $user, "test_message" ));
```

Hope it helps somebody else

Comment: You have created a very good class, its really very helpfull :)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to follow the documentation: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html

You can specify the template_id in the embedded data:

```
Mail::send('emails.share', ['content' => 'foo'], function (Message $message) {
        $message
            ->subject('Test')
            ->to('me@jakubkratina.cz', 'foo_name')
            ->from('bar@example.com', 'bar_name')
            ->embedData([
                'custom_args' => [
                    'user_id' => "123" // Make sure this is a string value
                ],
                'template_id' => 'your-template-id'
            ], 'sendgrid/x-smtpapi');
    });
```

So easy :-)

Edit: 
Your view's content will be passed into the <%body%> variable in the template editor.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent some time on this problem and got it to work..

Make sure you use "sendgrid/sendgrid": ">=5.0.1",

the example code using templates can be found [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/mail/mail.php%20here)

Comment: I used html template for that.but I would like to know about this and where to put "sendgrid/sendgrid": ">=5.0.1" ? your link gives 404 error

Comment: That would be composer.json  .. Also I didn't mention that I'm using Laravel 5.3

Comment: Thanks @Peachyz. I am using Laravel 5.1. It may be the problem.